# Array and String as Parameter for Soap in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I can't pass array and string as parameter in a variable.

Following is my code which is not working as expected.

```
$wsdlParams = array(
        array(     
            'webserviceid' => $WebServiceID,
            'webservicepass' =>  $WebServicePassword
        ),$fde);

    $soapclient = new SoapClient($WebServiceURL);
    $soapresult = $soapclient->MyInfo($wsdlParams);
```

Working One:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($WebServiceURL);
$soapresult = $soapclient->MyInfo(array('webserviceid' => $WebServiceID,'webservicepass' => $WebServicePassword),$fde);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (splat) operator to expand your array of parameters into the necessary two arguments for `myInfo`:

```
$soapresult = $soapclient->MyInfo(...$wsdlParams);
```

Comment: I didn't know anything about splat... its work great. thanx. is there any other solution?

Comment: @UFO you could use `$soapresult = $soapclient->MyInfo($wsdlParams[0], $wsdlParams[1]);` but the splat operator is a much nicer way of writing it.